# как сделать так, чтобы при запуске main функция вызвана была всего один раз

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при запуске функции, запускались вебхуки и сохранили данные. То и есть данные на один запуск. Бот телеграм пишу. Чтобы не тратить ресурсы, пользователи много раз будут узнала цену на товар. Поэтому нужно, чтобы один раз все нашлось и хранилось в памяти.

Я отправляю вебхуки на сайт, их три и они проходят через функции

```
def get_access_token():
    # отправка и получение данных вебхука
    return token
def get_point_list():
    # отправка и получение данных вебхука
    return response
def get_price_list():
    # отправка и получение данных вебхука
    return response
```

Я делал вызов этих функции после

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

но без результата. Мозг ломал целый день, закидывал это в файл, потом импортировал, но без успеха.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    company_token = get_access_token()
    company_point = get_point_list()
    company_price = get_price_list()
```

**Все переменные с company должны использоваться в main и должны созданы в начале кода. Код имеет асинхронный api. Также переменные company словари.**

**И второй вопрос:** я принтую, например company_token, в конце кода и он не выводиться, почему так происходит?

Comment: Чтобы данные каждый раз не запрашивались заново, используйте кэширование. Есть кэширующий декоратор в стандартной библиотеке: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.cache, есть асинхронные реализации, например https://github.com/aio-libs/async-lru. "И второй вопрос" - не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать это с помощью класса.Тогда у тебя переменные буду получать значения при инициализации класса и это будет случаться только один раз, при запуске программы(при условии, что класс ты больше нигде инициализировать не будешь)

```
class <Имя класса>:
       def __init__(self):
              self.company_token = get_access_token()
              self.company_point = get_point_list()
              self.company_price = get_price_list()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = <Имя класса>()
```

По второму вопросу - хотелось бы конкретно увидеть что и где принтуешь, мб переменная пустая